# How can I change the font of section numbers such as \thechapter?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, numbering, koma-script, scrbook

I would like to change the font of the chapter and section numbers appearing in my titles. I found that I can change the number style from arabic to roman etc. but I couldn't find a way to change the font of the number itself.

When I tried changing the font of the chapter heading it changed only the heading title text and not the numbering. So I get "1.1" in times roman and "section name" in sans serif :/

I tried using `sectsty`, `titlesec` and renewing the `\chapter` command.

class definition is: `\documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper,pointlessnumbers,headsepline,idxtotoc]{scrbook}`

Any tips or advice would be great!

Comment: maybe the package `sectsty` can help you.

Comment: I didn't try to change it, but in the `memoir` class I think you can change the `\makechapterstyle{section}` in the `memoir.cls`. I did something similar to the `chapter` style. I guess something similar exists in `scrbook`.

Comment: Please indicate which document class you're using. Are you using one of the koma-script document classes? If so, which one?

Comment: @Mico: Apparently she (?) made the tagging herself. (@NoaTamir: No offence intended.)

Comment: What I do not understand: In KOMA-script the default _are_ sans serif fonts for disposition/sectioning. Did you confuse the numbers? But compare for instance `\documentclass{scrbook} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{libertine} \usepackage{blindtext} \begin{document} \blinddocument \end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers, I didn't know I wasn't suppose to tag myself(?!) - but yes, I am using scrbook.

Comment: Noa, English is not my natural language.

Comment: Hi everyone, I think I found the rouge line of code that caused al my problems `\def\mbox#1{\textrm{#1}}
` was among the long list of predefined definitions and I was able to recreate the problem with the sample text as well. I have no clue why it was there to begin with but my chapter numbers are back in order now. 
if anyone is interested I am happy to post the sample with the problem, just let me know. Thanks again for your comments and help!

Answer (score 7):

From the tagging, it seems that you are using `KOMAscript` and the class `scrbook`. Then you change the font either with  `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont` (see section 3.6, page 51 in [the revised manual](http://www.komascript.de/files/scrguien.pdf)), and with the modifier `chapterprefix`. Try:

```
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\rmfamily\Large\bfseries}
```

or, to change to a serif typeface only:

```
\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\rmfamily}
```

To change all sectioning to the default Roman font, reverse all font changes you have done to `chapter`, and try

```
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
```

It seems from your comment that somebody has tampered with the definitions in your classfile. This minimal example works for me, giving me sans serif in heading and body text.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper,pointlessnumbers,headsepline,idxtotoc]{scrb‌​ook}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

In your document, comment out (or delete) all `usepackage{secsty}` etc. that changes the headings. Or add packages and commands from you preamble to my code.

If you are going to use Helvetica as sans serif font, I suggest  using the Tex-Gyre version instead, by loading the package `tgheros`. I have changed my MWE correspondingly.

Comment: I tried `\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\sffamily}`
but it didn't change the numbers to sans serif. I'm working on a project I didn't start I'm afraid and the entire book is in `\rmfamily` despite the fact the default should be sans serif, as @Speravir pointed out in the comments above. It's a very messy project I'm afraid, I couldn't find where they changed the font family.
This is the class definition:

`\documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper,pointlessnumbers,headsepline,idxtotoc]{scrbook}`

Comment: I have added a MWE to my answer that gives sans serif (Helvetica) for text and headings.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way you can change the number formatting:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper,pointlessnumbers,headsepline,idxtotoc]{scrbook}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{% Chapter number formatting
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}{\normalfont\itshape\thechapter}\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{% Section number formatting
   \protect\othersectionlevelsformat{#1}{%
     \expandafter\aftergroup\noexpand\@gobble}{\normalfont\itshape\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
Here is some text
\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

Printing of the chapter and section numbers are done by `\chapterformat` and `\@seccntformat`, respectively. In the above MWE I've inserted `\normalfont\itshape` which you can change to your liking/preference. It should also be possible to do this a little cleaner using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the class you are using, this is a very general answer. Here `sectsty` package is used. A MWE will be:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sf}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{First chapter}
  This is first chapter
  \section{First section}
  First section and
  \subsection{Also first}
  First sub section
  \subsubsection{Again first}
  What do you think?
  \section{Second section}
  And here is second section.
  \chapter{Second chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks. I was bit lazy to be elaborate. I think that sentance itself is not required when we have a picture.